# JQUERY Validate - serialise select and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the validate plugin in order to send some `ajax`. I am having the problem that I cannot serialise `select option` and `checkbox`.

My end result is to have a string looking like `dashName=aaa&dashSurname=bbb&dashArea=Blue...`

With the code below I can just get the `input text` values; How can I validate and get the values from other elements?

here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxf996cg/)

```
  $('#updateMemberForm').validate();

  $(document).on('click', '#saveMemberBtn', function() {

    if ($('#updateMemberForm').valid()) {

      var serialize = $("#updateMemberForm").serialize();

      $("#test").text(serialize);
      console.log(serialize);


    }
    return false;
  });
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="updateMemberForm">
  <input class="" type="text" name="dashName" placeholder="Name" />
  <input class="" type="text" name="dashSurname" placeholder="Surname" />
  <br>
  <select onchange="" name="dashArea">
    <option value="" selected disabled>AREA</option>
    <option value="Red">RED</option>
    <option value="Blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="Green">GREEN</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input class="" type="text" name="dashAddress" placeholder="Address" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="dash_enable">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="" id="saveMemberBtn" value="SAVE" />
</form>
```

Comment: In your fiddle I am getting what seems to be your desired result, `dashName=john&dashSurname=doe&dashArea=Blue&dashAddress=5+elm+st&dash_enable=on`, am I missing something?

Comment: tried on safari itworks

Comment: Seems I cannot get the checkbox off value

Comment: If it's not there it's off. If you really want it though, you could use a `hidden` input and update the value of that when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: The checkbox is only included in the post data if it's checked. Normally the server-side code just checks whether the parameter is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `SAVE` button is a `type="submit"`, you would not need a `click` handler to capture it and test validity.  The `submithandler` built into the plugin is already doing this for you.

```
$('#updateMemberForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) { // only fires when valid
        var serialize = $("#updateMemberForm").serialize();

        $("#test").text(serialize);
        console.log(serialize);

        // AJAX goes here

        return false;
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/rsfonzL7/**

As already mentioned in the comments, when a checkbox is not checked, nothing is sent in the query string, and this is handled on the server side.  This has nothing to do with jQuery Validate or `.serialize()`... this is just how form data is constructed and sent, no matter the method.